# Gmail to google sheet parse data with rich text format

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets, gmail

I have been using Google apps' script to parse gmail data using regex. Mail is read within a specific gmail label which come from one sender, as in code below:

```
   //  Adapted from https://gist.github.com/Ferrari/9678772
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345400/extract-info-from-email-body-with-google-scripts

function processInboxToSheet() {

// Have to get data separate to avoid google app script limit!

var start = 0;
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Any label name here");
var threads = label.getThreads();

var SPREADSHEET_URL = "Any google sheet URL in here ";
var SHEET_NAME = 'Required Sheet tab name here';
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
var qs_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
var result = [];



for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();

// implement your own parsing rule inside
if (content) {
  tmp = content.match(/Transaction Reference:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.,-]+)/);
  var TransactionReference = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No data';

  tmp = content.match(/Transaction Date:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.,-]+)/);
  var TransactionDate = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No data';

  tmp = content.match(/Transaction Charges:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.,-]+)/);
  var TransactionCharges = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No data';

  tmp = content.match(/Beneficiary Name:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.,'-]+\s*[[A-Za-z0-9@.,'-]+)/);
  var BeneficiaryName = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No data';

  tmp = content.match(/Exchange Rate:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.,-]+)/);
  var ExchangeRate = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No data';

  tmp = content.match(/Beneficiary Amount:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.,-]+)/);
  var BeneficiaryAmount = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No data';

  tmp = content.match(/Total Amount Debited from your card:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.,-]+)/);
  var SterlingAmount = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No data';


  qs_sheet.appendRow([TransactionReference, TransactionDate, TransactionCharges, BeneficiaryName,ExchangeRate,BeneficiaryAmount,SterlingAmount]);

  Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
};
```

The script was working fine until the information started coming in rich text format.By looking at the original source it seems it is :

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

I am assuming the function `getPlainBody()` does not working with this, any idea how this can be corrected ?

Thanks for reading